# How to determine the number of method calls (or specific lines) of code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

How to determine the number of method calls (or specific lines) of code in Android Studio? I would like to see the result as in the screenshot right in the code (this is from another IDE, «1C»)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66n0b.png)

I start the application on AVD, perform some UI actions (in my case, it’s a scrolling of RecycledView), close the application. I would like to know which code was executed and which was not. I tried to look towards Code Coverage, but it runs only for Unit tests, and they do not allow (?) to simulate interactive actions.  Also I formed diagrams in Profiler, for example, the Top Down diagram, but it does not give a picture in general, it is not visible which methods were NOT called, and there are no number of calls of invoked methods.

Comment: Try Inspect code feature of android code which suggest all possible improvements for you code including unused code. In case of Adapter better put break points in methods and run application in debug mode once you can recognize method called and not called

Comment: Vinayak Khedkar, I want to understand which code is not called in a particular session, but is not used at all. The code can be called or not - it depends on the actions in the UI.
Manually setting breakpoints is understandable, but an automatic tool is needed.

Comment: Check out these tools they might help. i have not used them but you can give a try https://github.com/mre/awesome-static-analysis